# Creating N-Dimensional "Permutation" Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, permutation

I would like to create a n-dimensional matrix containing all possible combinations with array values between -1 and +1.

**So for n = 2 this would look like to following:**

```
[[-1,-1], [-1,0], [-1,+1], [0,-1], [0,0], [0,+1], [1,-1], [1,0], [1,1]]
```

*The matrix itself will be used to calculate surrounding points of an object.*

I already wrote a quite simple solution using multiple for loops, but I would like the solution to be independent from the dimension. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def n_dims(dims, start, stop):
    if dims == 1:
            return list(map(lambda x: [x], range(start, stop)))
    else:
            p = n_dims(dims - 1, start, stop)
            a = []
            for i in range(start, stop):
                    a += [j + [i] for j in p]
            return a
```

This appeared to work in python 3. Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice recursion :) Would have never figured that one out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an opportunity to play with functions in the itertools module that I normally don't have a need for:

```
from itertools import product, repeat

def n_dimensional_matrix(n, start=-1, stop=1):
    return product(*repeat(range(start, stop+1), n))
```

Now try the 2 dimensional example:

```
>>> matrix = n_dimensional_matrix(2)
>>> 
>>> print(list(matrix))
[(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Heman Gandhi has clarified what the output for greater dimensions should be (thank you):

```
>>> list(n_dimensional_matrix(3))
[(-1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 0), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 0, -1), (-1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 1), (0, -1, -1), (0, -1, 0), (0, -1, 1), (0, 0, -1), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, -1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 1), (1, 0, -1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: This is awesome! I think the key difference is that (it looked like) Phillip Braun wanted the `range(-1, 2)` regardless of dimension.

Comment: Thank you @HemanGandhi, I've tweaked my solution accordingly.